# How to define a variable with multiple independent if statements?

Tags: python

I'm trying to define a variable for easy reference elsewhere in the code. It has multiple independent if statements, so I am wondering how to do it. The code below triggers a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

```
CaseCaption = \
if PCount > 1:
    replace_last(',\r'.join(tables['Plaintiffs']['Plaintiffs']).upper(),',\r',', and \r') + \
else:
    join(tables['Plaintiffs']['Plaintiffs']).upper() + \
',\r\r\tPlaintiffs,\r\rv.\r\r' + \
if DCount > 1:
    replace_last(',\r'.join(tables['Defendants'].get('Defendants')).upper(),',\r',', and \r') + \
        ',\r\r\tDefendants.'
else:
    join(tables['Defendants']['Defendants']).upper()
```

Comment: `var = value1 if condition1 else value2 if condition2 else value3`

Comment: ... but if the values and/or conditions are fairly long as in your example, I would recommend doing the assignments inside the if/else blocks for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John Gordon. I ended up solving the problem with the code below. I hoped there was a more elegant solution than nested if statements. For example, what if I needed to define a variable based on many different conditions and/or criteria? Is the best solution to add more nested if statements? I could see that getting unwieldy quickly. If anyone knows a better solution that can handle more complex variables, please let me know. Here's the code:

```
if PCount > 1:
    if DCount > 1:
        CaseCaption = replace_last(',\r'.join(tables['Plaintiffs']['Plaintiffs']).upper(), ',\r', ', and \r') + \
        ',\r \r \t Plaintiffs, \r\r v. \r\r' + replace_last(',\r'.join(tables['Defendants'].get('Defendants')).upper(),',\r',', and \r') + \
            ',\r\r\tDefendants.'
    else:
        CaseCaption = replace_last(',\r'.join(tables['Plaintiffs']['Plaintiffs']).upper(), ',\r', ', and \r') + \
                      ',\r \r \t Plaintiffs, \r\r v. \r\r' + tables['Defendants']['Defendants'][0].upper() + \
                      ',\r\r\tDefendant.'
else:
    if DCount > 1:
        CaseCaption = tables['Plaintiffs']['Plaintiffs'][0].upper() + \
        ',\r\r\t Plaintiff,\r\rv.\r\r' + replace_last(',\r'.join(tables['Defendants'].get('Defendants')).upper(),',\r',', and \r') + \
            ',\r\r\tDefendants.'
    else:
        CaseCaption = tables['Plaintiffs']['Plaintiffs'][0].upper() + \
                      ',\r \r \t Plaintiff, \r\r v. \r\r' + tables['Defendants']['Defendants'][0].upper() + \
                      ',\r\r\tDefendant.'
```